# partition a string by dash (-) python

Tags: python

I want to get a string and divide it into parts separated by "-".
Input:

```
aabbcc
```

And output:

```
aa-bb-cc
```

is there a way to do so?

Comment: exactly after 2 characters?

Comment: @SachinKukreja Yup

Comment: The string length is variable?

Comment: @guillermochamorro it's dividable by  two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it based on the same letter then you can use `itertools.groupby()` to do this, e.g.:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
s = 'aabbcc'
'-'.join(''.join(g) for k, g in it.groupby(s))

Out[]:
'aa-bb-cc'
```

Or if you want it in chunks of `2` you can use `iter()` and `zip()`:

```
In []:
n = 2
'-'.join(''.join(p) for p in zip(*[iter(s)]*n))

Out[]:
'aa-bb-cc'
```

Note: if the string length is not divisible by 2 this will drop the last character - you can replace `zip(...)` with `itertools.zip_longest(..., fillvalue='')` but it is unclear if the OP has this issue)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider creating pair-divided by a dash, you can use the below function:

```
def pair_div(string):
    newString=str() #for storing the divided string
    for i,s in enumerate(string):
        if i%2!=0 and i<(len(string)-1):   #we make sure the function divides every two chars but not the last character of string.
            newString+=s+'-'               #If it is the second member of pair, add a dash after it
        else:
            newString+=s                   #If not, just add the character
    return(newString)
```

And for example:

```
[In]:string="aazzxxcceewwqqbbvvaa"
[Out]:'aa-zz-xx-cc-ee-ww-qq-bb-vv-aa'
```

But if you consider dividing same characters as a group and separate with a dash, you better your regex methods.

BR,
Shend

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
data = "aabbcc"
"-".join([data[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(data), 2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to divide the string into block of 2 characters, then this will help you.

```
import textwrap
s='aabbcc'
lst=textwrap.wrap(s,2)
print('-'.join(lst))
```

2nd attribute defines the no. of characters you want in a particular group

Comment: 2nd attribute defines the no. of characters you want in a particular group

Comment: @AChampion Ok, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

```
s =   'aabbccdd'
#index 01234567 
new_s = ''
```

1)

```
for idx, char in enumerate(s):
    new_s+=char
    if  idx%2 != 0:
        new_s += '-'

print(new_s.strip('-'))
# aa-bb-cc-dd
```

2)

```
new_s = ''.join([s[i]+'-' if i%2 != 0  else s[i] for i in range(len(s))]).strip('-')
print(new_s)

# aa-bb-cc-dd
```